# Получение значения из объекта

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть объект `$order` :

```
object(APP_Instant_Order)#12954 (10) {
["statuses":protected]=>
array(4) {
["tr_pending"]=>
string(7) "pending"
["tr_failed"]=>
string(6) "failed"
["tr_completed"]=>
string(9) "completed"
["tr_activated"]=>
string(9) "activated"
}
["id":protected]=>
int(384)
["parent":protected]=>
int(0)
["state":protected]=>
string(10) "tr_pending"
        ...
```

Необходимо получить значение `id`. Почему-то `$order->id` выводит `NULL`

Comment: потому что он protected  - защищенный, а не public - публичный. добавьте публичное свойство геттер public getId()

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а можете подсказать как обращаться объекту который находится внутри объекта?

Comment: Сделать его публичным или добавить в класс метод, который получает  Id, как подсказали выше. (Первое быстрее)

Comment: Посмотрите описание в документации или в коде библиотеки для класса `APP_Instant_Order`. Скорее всего у него уже есть геттер, или он не нужен.